# How to setup Apache Kafka consumer to get data across internet?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I've configured 2 Kafka with basic settings  on two different servers across the net one in the UK and another one in India and my scenario is very simple the UK is publisher and India is consumer but none of them can get any data.

I've checked my firewalls there is not port blocking/ whatsoever. Also I've tested my scenario with redis pubsub and it worked but I wasn't successful with Kafka.

How should I setup my Kafkas to do such? or is it possible at all to do such with Kafka?

Comment: Do you have 2 Kafka clusters or a single cluster with one producer and one consumer? When in doubt I always try to connect to Kafka with command line tools like kafka-console-consumer.

Comment: I have one producer and consumer and I am using kafka-console-producer / kafka-console-consumer with the same topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :

In Apache Kafka's config, add following line :

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp
# x = your IP
# p = your port
```

Answer (score 2):

Kafka is not recommended when you want to interact from multiple data centres. Kafka is designed to give you high-throughput given you are producing and consuming from the same data centre where network latency is minimal.

Why ?

Once you have consumers in a different data centre the latency comes to play affecting all coordination that Kafka does with consumers (group rebalancing/offset commits/heartbeats) and producers being in a different data centre the latency for getting acks for each message send will be considerable, slowing down the rate at which you can produce messages.

So, in theory, you can very well have the setup if your network is reliable.

Now If you are thinking to have Kafka brokers distributed among data centres, it will be more costly. All the inter-broker communication will be delayed effectively creating lag in replicas, lotof network calls(over the internet), broker heartbeat timeouts etc, again theoretically feasible.

In practice for these scenarios, it is better to have local Kafka cluster for each DC where they produce/consume messages with applications hosted locally and have [Mirrormaker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330) to aggregate messages between data centres.

Comment: I have brokers cross data center accidentally(same city, near data center), the inter-broker replication cost increase 16%.

Comment: any suggestion for distributed pub/sub queue?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on your use case ? In case if you don't want all messages in other dc in absolute real time you can go for Kafka + Mirrormaker.